# Whether this series convergent or not? (A series related to Euler constant $\gamma$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\displaystyle a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-\ln n$, and its limit exists, which I have proved and the limit is the famous Euler's constant $\gamma$.
My approach is as follows:

Noting that $$\displaystyle\ln n=\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x$$
and that
$$\forall x\in[k,k+1],\frac{1}{k+1}\leqslant\frac{1}{x}\leqslant \frac{1}{k}$$
Hence
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-\ln n\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \geqslant \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}\mathrm{d}x\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{n}\geqslant 0$$
On the other hand, $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{k+1}-\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \leqslant \frac{1}{k+1}-\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k+1}\mathrm{d}x=0$$
Namely $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence, hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists.

But whether the series   $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n-\gamma)$$
convergent or not?
I don't know which direction I should try.

Comment: It is hard to know what tools are available to you without more context. Perhaps if you showed how you determined that the limit existed it might be possible to work from that.

Comment: You can find in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number that $a_n - \gamma \sim 1/(2n)$.

Comment: Ok, I've added more context of how I proved the $a_n$ convergent.

Comment: Thanks! I've posted my answer.

Comment: If we set $b_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\log\left(n+\frac12\right)$, then the sum $\sum\limits(b_n-\gamma)$ [converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/804185).

Answer (score 2):

The sum $\ \sum_\limits{k=1}^n\big(a_n-\gamma)\ $, as you've written it, reduces to $\ n\big(a_n-\gamma\big)\ $, and since it's known that $
\frac{1}{2n+1}\le\big(a_n-\gamma\big)\le\frac{1}{2n}$, (as Martin R points out in his comment) then you get $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_\limits{k=1}^n\big(a_n-\gamma)=\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}n\big(a_n-\gamma\big)=\frac{1}{2}\ $.   If you meant to write $\ \sum_\limits{k=1}^n\big(a_k-\gamma)\ $ instead, then that series diverges by comparison with the harmonic series, because $\ \frac{1}{2(k+1)}\le a_k-\gamma\ $.

Comment: Please read [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: Sorry , I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

**The Series Diverges**
$$
\begin{align}
a_n-a_{n+1}
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\log(n)\right)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1k-\log(n+1)\right)\tag{1a}\\
&=\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)-\frac1{n+1}\tag{1b}\\
&=-\log\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)-\frac1{n+1}\tag{1c}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k+1)(n+1)^{k+1}}\tag{1d}\\
&\ge\frac1{2(n+1)^2}+\frac1{3(n+1)^3}\tag{1e}\\
&\ge\frac1{2(n+1/2)(n+3/2)}\tag{1f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ definition
$\text{(1b):}$ subtract
$\text{(1c):}$ $1+\frac1n=\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{-1}$
$\text{(1d):}$ use the series for $\log(1-x)$
$\text{(1e):}$ the infinite sum is greater than the sum of the first two terms
$\text{(1f):}$ $\frac1{2(n+1/2)(n+3/2)}-\frac1{2(n+1)^2}=\frac1{8(n+1/2)(n+3/2)(n+1)^2}\le\frac1{3(n+1)^3}$ 
$$
\begin{align}
a_n-\gamma
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty(a_k-a_{k+1})\tag{2a}\\
&\ge\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{2(k+1/2)(k+3/2)}\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\frac1{k+1/2}-\frac1{k+3/2}\right)\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac1{2n+1}\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ the series telescopes and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\gamma$
$\text{(2b):}$ apply $(1)$
$\text{(2c):}$ partial fractions
$\text{(2d):}$ telescoping series

Thus, the sum diverges by comparison to the Harmonic series.

---

**Compute an Upper Bound**
$$
\begin{align}
a_n-a_{n+1}
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\log(n)\right)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1k-\log(n+1)\right)\tag{3a}\\
&=\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)-\frac1{n+1}\tag{3b}\\
&=-\log\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)-\frac1{n+1}\tag{3c}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(k+1)(n+1)^{k+1}}\tag{3d}\\
&\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2(n+1)^{k+1}}\tag{3e}\\
&=\frac1{2n(n+1)}\tag{3f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a):}$ definition
$\text{(3b):}$ subtract
$\text{(3c):}$ $1+\frac1n=\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{-1}$
$\text{(3d):}$ use the series for $\log(1-x)$
$\text{(3e):}$ $k+1\ge2$
$\text{(3f):}$ sum the geometric series
$$
\begin{align}
a_n-\gamma
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty(a_k-a_{k+1})\tag{4a}\\
&\le\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{2k(k+1)}\tag{4b}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)\tag{4c}\\
&=\frac1{2n}\tag{4d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a):}$ the series telescopes and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\gamma$
$\text{(4b):}$ apply $(3)$
$\text{(4c):}$ partial fractions
$\text{(4d):}$ telescoping series

Thus, we have shown that
$$
\frac1{2n+1}\le a_n-\gamma\le\frac1{2n}\tag5
$$

---

**A Second Approach**

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/804185), it is shown that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n-\log\left(n+\frac12\right)-\gamma\right)=\gamma+\frac12-\frac32\log(2)\tag6
$$
Since $a_n-\gamma=\left(H_n-\log\left(n+\frac12\right)-\gamma\right)+\left(\log\left(n+\frac12\right)-\log(n)\right)$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n-\gamma)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n-\log\left(n+\frac12\right)-\gamma\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\log\left(n+\frac12\right)-\log(n)\right)\tag7
$$
However, since $\log(1+x)\le x$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(n+\frac12\right)-\log(n)
&=-\log\left(1-\frac1{2n+1}\right)\tag{8a}\\
&\ge\frac1{2n+1}\tag{8b}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, the series on the left of $(7)$ diverges because it is the sum of a convergent series and a series which diverges by comparison to the Harmonic Series.

Comment: In $\text{(1f)}$, we could have simply noted that $\frac1{(n+1)^2}\ge\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2}$, not even using the cubic term, and gotten that $a_n-\gamma\ge\frac1{2n+2}$, but this argument gets a slightly better bound.